# Hbase read high load

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, hdfs, high-availability

I'm in research process for noSQL solution for our company needs. 
For now the search narrows to hBase. I've read a lot about architecture, performance etc, but one thing is still uncovered for me.

For example if you have 100 nodes cluster, and one row gets 100.000 simultaneous requests. In this case all the 100.000 requests will hit only one node, where the row is stored? As I understand HBase replication is only for data backup (not for read load balance), and there no any master/slave mechanism (like in MySQL)?

Comment: You should add a cache in front of HBase, this will reduce the load on HBase. Try EHCache.

Comment: thanks for sharing the EHCache, I'm looking into it. Looks like sort of Memcache/Membase solution. But I was thinking HBase has in-built cache/balance load mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to 100.000 concurrent requests for single row - I think nobody is good for this currently. Under normal condition it is simply not needed - clients are anyway isolated from DB so access is limited in this case (and probably cached).

Regarding to storage and replication. First, there is at least 2 types of replication and actually it is not HBase. HBase relies on HDFS which is fault tolerant by nature. Read about `HBase master` and `HBase region server` role if you need to understand details but in general all things related to replication go to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 100,000 concurrent request will not work very well on HBase, however real world scenarios seems to work quite well 
[yfrog get 10K request per second](http://www.slideshare.net/jacque74/hug-hbase-presentation?player=js) and [eBay chose it for the new version of their product search engine](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/hadoop-world-2011-keynote-ebay-hugh-williams) as well as [Facebook for their messaging system](http://www.slideshare.net/brizzzdotcom/facebook-messages-hbase)
You can also take a look at [hstack benchmarks](http://hstack.org/hbase-performance-testing/) on more modest cluster

Answer (score 0):

HBase replication is not only for data backup, also availability. As that does not seem to be the only point you cover with your question here I pointed you to that link where you can find more information. If you have specific questions regarding your schema design you should start in the home page of the Apache hosted project first of all. For the last question mark about master/slave, that URL I sent still applies (And you can ask the HBase developers about it if you are unsure anyway): http://hbase.apache.org/replication.html